# Finding each change for input in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, events, onchange

I have an input in html. I want to be aware on each changing on its content. I know that there is .change function in jquery. But it triggers when you focus on/out the input. I want when user typing in input, for each letter a function will be called. Is there any way to it?

Comment: as @kei mention : use keyup, http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#yourinput").on("keyup",function(){
   //do stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about use `input event` ? It's not a cross browser way but it should do the trick.
It triggers when the text has been changed, so you can navigate thrue arrow keys and it won't be triggered.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/KUtDp/)

Or you can store the last input text and compare with the actual on `keyup` for a cross browser way.

*References*:
 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/input